# For nonnegative function, does $\int_0^\infty f(x)dx$ converge or diverge to $\infty$?

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

Let $f$ be a nonnegative continuous function defined on $[a,\infty)$.

Consider $\displaystyle\int_a^\infty f(x) dx=\lim_{M\to \infty}\ \int_a^M f(x) dx$.

Let $\mathcal F:=\left\{\displaystyle\int_a^M f(x) dx \right\}_{M>a}$

Then, does $$\displaystyle\int_a^\infty f(x) dx=\begin{cases}\mathrm{converges}  &\mathrm{if}\ \mathcal F \ \mathrm{is \ bounded} \\ \infty  &\mathrm{if}\ \mathcal F \ \mathrm{is \ unbounded} \end{cases} \tag{$*$} $$ hold ?

I think this problem is similar to that of sequence.

For $\{ a_n\}_{n=1}^\infty\ ,$ if $a_n\geqq 0$ and $a_n\leqq a_{n+1}$ hold, then $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to \infty}a_n=
\begin{cases}\mathrm{converges}  &\mathrm{if}\ \mathcal \{ a_n\}_{n=1}^\infty \ \mathrm{is \ bounded} \\ \infty  &\mathrm{if}\ \mathcal \{ a_n\}_{n=1}^\infty \ \mathrm{is \ unbounded} \end{cases}
  \tag{$\bigstar$} $

As for $\mathcal F$, $\displaystyle\int_a^M f(x) dx \geqq 0 $ for all $M>a$ and $\displaystyle\int_a^M f(x) dx \leqq \displaystyle\int_a^N f(x) dx $ for $M\leqq N$, so I expect that $\displaystyle\lim_{M\to \infty}\int_a^M f(x) dx= \begin{cases}\mathrm{converges}  &\mathrm{if}\ \mathcal F \ \mathrm{is \ bounded} \\ \infty  &\mathrm{if}\ \mathcal F \ \mathrm{is \ unbounded} \end{cases}$ holds.

Is this correct ?

I'm not sure my idea is correct or not because $n$ is discrete parameter but $M$ is continuous parameter.

Or, perhaps, can I prove $(\ast)$ using $(\bigstar)$ ?

Comment: I suppose we are assuming that $f$ is integrable on finite intervals?

Comment: If $f$ is integrable, defined on $[a,\infty)$, doesn't that mean $\int_a^{\infty}f$ converges?

Comment: Indeed, yes.  I checked the reference and it supposes $f$ is continuous. @GerryMyerson

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $g(x)=\int_a^{x}f(t)dt$. Then $g$ is an increasing function $[a,\infty)$. This implies that $\lim_{x \to \infty} g(x)=\sup_{x>a} g(x)$ (which may be finite or $+\infty$). So it  follows trivially that the improper Riemann integral of $f$ exists if and only if $g$ is bounded.